# Mvc. Отправка данных Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

Есть модальное окно для авторизации, данные отправляется по *ajax*. На главной странице(*localhost*) данные получаю нормально, *json*. При попытке авторизоваться на одной из внутренних страниц(*localhost/products*, *localhost/category* и тд), *Ajax* выдает текст *html* страницы. Сайт на *MVC*.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'user/register',
  type: 'POST',
  data: $form,
  success: function($data) {
    alert($data);
  }
});
```

Подскажите в чем проблема? Заранее спасибо!)

```
class Route { 
    static function start() 
    {   
        // контроллер и действие по умолчанию 
        $controller_name = 'index'; 
        $action_name = 'index'; 
        $action = ''; 
        $routes = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
        // получаем имя контроллера 
        if ( !empty($routes[1]) ) 
        {    
            $controller_name = $routes[1]; 
        }   
        // получаем имя экшена 
        if ( !empty($routes[2]) ) 
        { 
           $action_name = $routes[2]; 
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: приложение какой язык использует? где в вопросе хотя бы симантика контроллера?

Comment: Всем спасибо,  Url указал полностью, и все данные получаю нужные

Answer (score 2):

Правильней будет указывать урл хелперами вашего фреймворка в `hidden` поле.
А в `ajax` запросе получать его через `id` данного поля.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $.ajax({
      url: '/user/register',
      type: 'POST',
      data: $form,
      success: function($data) {
        alert($data);
      }
    });
```

вот так попробуйте

Comment: пробовал, и пробовал полностью указать url

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать `Content-Type: text/plain`